# Background overlapping the vision of my other JLabels

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jlabel

I'm creating a very simple game with JFrame and JLabels, I managed to make it work but at the time of placing a background I'm finding a problem. The image I set as background is covering my other JLabels (they still work behind but you can't see them).

```
public class Game extends JPanel {
    
    Player p1 = new Player(this, 'a');
    Player p2 = new Player(this, 'r');
    
    public Game() {}
    
    public void move() {}
    public void gameOver() {}
    
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        p1.paint(g2d);
        p2.paint(g2d);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(not relevant));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window");
        JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
        Game game = new Game();
        
        
        frame.add(game);
        frame.add(background);
        
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        while (true) {
            game.move();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }

}
```

I think the problem comes from using my class Game(which is the one that "runs" the game) as a JPanel and then in the Main creating a JFrame and adding it… if there is no way to solve this I will change it but would like to keep it like it is now.
I've tried to swap the:

frame.add(game);
frame.add(background);

but the outcomes are:

game-->background--> you can only see the background but still can play the game

background-->game--> you can only see a mini-window (with no size, only minimize, maximize and close) but still can play the game.

Also tried to create the background image in the Game class but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A JFrame’s content pane uses a BorderLayout by default, which means `add(game)` will place the Game component in the center of the BorderLayout.  A BorderLayout can only have one center component at a time, so `add(background)` replaces the old center component (game) with the background JLabel.

An easy solution is to avoid using a JLabel for the background, and just paint the background in your paint method:

```
g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
p1.paint(g2d);
p2.paint(g2d);
```

This will require a private field of type BufferedImage (or just Image) in your Game class, which you can set in that class’s constructor.

Note that you should almost always override [paintComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) rather than paint:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // ...
}
```

For all of the details regarding painting of Swing components, see https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html.

**Update**:  It would appear that your `background` JLabel was defining the size of the JFrame’s contents when the JFrame’s `pack()` method was called.

Once your background JLabel has been removed, the only remaining component (an instance of the `Game` class) must define its own preferred size, so that when the JFrame’s `pack()` method is called, it will know what size the contents of the JFrame wish to be.  You can do this by having the Game class report its preferred size explicitly:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
}
```

That will require `img` to be of type BufferedImage, since the zero-argument getWidth and getHeight methods don’t exist in the Image class.

Comment: Grat explanation and very easy to understand, the problem i posted is now corrected but with how is made the JFrame now, i cant use the frame.pack(); line and for some reason when i use frame.setSize() and the pixels the image should be(as its said by the properties of the file), the window is not big enough... could you help me with this?

Comment: @Piti Updated answer.  A JPanel’s preferred size is 0×0 pixels by default, but subclasses can report what they believe their ideal size should be, by overriding the `getPreferredSize` method.